# How can I speed up this simple matrix multiplication in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I do not have much experience with Matlab, which is why I am asking this question here to get some directions to start looking.

I have this code:

```
A = A - A(:,i)*(A(i,:)/(delta + A(i,i)));
```

The A matrix is 216x31285, which means this computation is quite expensive for the number of times it is executed. It executes for all rows (216) for each data set (28) so naturally the 0.192 seconds it takes is quite a bit. Any ideas on how I can speed this up?

Comment: That depends of what delta is and what you need the code for

Comment: Are you working on a multiprocessor machine and do you have the parallel computing toolbox? If so, consider simply making it a `parfor` loop instead of a `for` loop ([link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/parfor.html)).

Note, this is one of those things that makes Matlab annoying. In Python, for example, your same code will essentially for the operation you want to do, but with the multiprocessing module, with PyCUDA, or with mpi4py, you can leverage multiprocessor or GPU performance without the extra cost of purchasing the parallel  computing toolbox.

Comment: And also note that this should be embarrassingly parallel across different data sets, so at the very least you can run a few different sessions of Matlab, each of which grabs new data sets as it finishes with the old ones.

Comment: This doesn't look right. You're indexing `i` from 1 to 216 but `A(:,i)` runs up to 31285. Are you sure it's not `A(i,:).*A(i,:)` you're after?

Comment: I ran this code on the GPU with Jacket and am getting a 100X speedup.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to speed up code in MATLAB is to take advantage of vectorization to get rid of loops. Instead of looping each line or column, attempt to apply whole operations instead, e.g., to multiply all lines of a matrix `M` with appropriate vector `V` do:

```
M = magic(5)
V = rand(5,1)
M = M.*repmat(V,[size(M,1) 1])
```

will in general work much faster than the equivalent for loop.

The actual implementation of vectorization is specific to each problem but very useful operators are the elementwise operators, e.g.: `.* ./ .^`, etc. Also the `repmat` function is extremely useful.

In your case however you are applying a recursive operation to matrix A:

```
A = A - f(i) = A - (prevA - f(i-1)) = ...
```

which means that you cannot apply all iterations at once as you would normally do when vectorizing code. 
In other words, at each iteration `i`, matrix `A` depends on matrix `A` at the previous iteration and therefore it is impossible to operate all iterations at once using the equation you provide.

Answer (score 1):

An addendum to @Pedro's answer.  If you have such a recursive equation you can usually trade space for time.

In the first step you update a matrix, say B (following Pedro's notation):

```
B = A - f(i)
```

in the second step you update A:

```
A = B - f(i)
```

in the third step, well that's the same as the first step.  And so on.